# Why extracting NEXRAD Level 3 products using the siphon package returns empty?

Tags: python-siphon

I am using the siphon package to extract NEXRAD Level 3 data following the example in this link: https://unidata.github.io/siphon/latest/examples/Radar_Server_Level_3.html. But it appears that the available **datasets** are empty. Does anyone know why and if there is a different package that I need to use to access NEXRAD Level 3 products? Thanks.

from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from siphon.cdmr import Dataset
from siphon.radarserver import get_radarserver_datasets, RadarServer

ds = get_radarserver_datasets('http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/')
print(list(ds))

url = ds['NEXRAD Level III Radar from IDD'].follow().catalog_url
rs = RadarServer(url)

print(rs.variables)

query = rs.query()
query.stations('FTG').time(datetime.utcnow()).variables('N0Q')

rs.validate_query(query)

catalog = rs.get_catalog(query)

print(catalog.datasets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the National Weather Service replaced the `N?Q` family of products (Digital Base Reflectivity) with "super-resolution" counterparts that have the identifier `N?B`, where `?` refers to the elevation of the product.

So for the example you reference, replace `N0Q` with `N0B` and everything should work as before.

Comment: Thanks much. I tested with N0B and it showed me the products I was looking for.